# cygwin linking error

Tags: boost, linker

I want to make network simulator shawn.exe with cygwin and that simulator need to boost library
when i call make for it in the linking step procedure break.
please help me,
this is all result of make command:

```
{.
.
[100%] Built target shawnlib
Scanning dependencies of target shawn
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/shawn.dir/frontend/console/con_main.o
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/shawn.dir/apps/apps_init.o
Linking CXX executable shawn.exe
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_regex-gcc-mt
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_date_time-gcc-mt
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_thread-gcc-mt
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/shawn.dir/build.make:111: recipe for target `shawn.exe' failed
make[2]: *** [shawn.exe] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:60: recipe for target `CMakeFiles/shawn.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/shawn.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:72: recipe for target `all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have the `libboost-devel` Cygwin package installed.  Re-run Cygwin's setup.exe and install that package (as well as its dependencies, which should automatically get installed if you don't explicitly exclude them).

Comment: Thanks alot. this is very helpful for me, best regards for you, be successfull

Comment: I didn't know there was boost package in Cygwin. I compiled boost from source and I get weird errors all around the code. This helped me a lot, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

no need to reinstall cygwin. just run:
`apt-cyg install libboost-devel`.
if you don't have "apt-cyg" installed, run these steps first:
`lynx -source rawgit.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg/master/apt-cyg > apt-cyg`
`install apt-cyg /bin`